# Apache Bench mark issue

Tags: php, apache2, apachebench

I ran apache benchmark like this (in localhost)

```
ab -n1000 -c10 http://someproject/
```

But none of the warning from site `http://someproject/` is  entered in to apache log file.

`ab` command ran well. It takes virtual host file and all the serverName written there, but it doesn't update log file which is mentioned in the virtual host file.

Can anybody can help ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `ab`, you should see the same behaviour if you access the site from any browser.

Comment: @ab is nothing but you are opening that site virtually using some browser, When i hit this link browser it populates my apache log file.

Answer (score 0):

Is it hitting the virtual host, or could it also be hitting the "default host" as specified by the root level documentroot directive? That's bitten me before.

Comment: @preinheimerc it is exactly hitting actual virtual host not the lt one.